# sorting files using header information

Tags: files, shell, text

I have multiple image files inside a directory having the same extension (.mrc). In the terminal, if I do, header , it gives following output:

RO image file on unit   1 : FoilHole_17224697_Data_18256098_18256099_20150819_2015.mrc     Size=      65537 K

```
     This file has invalid axis indices, adjusting them to 1,2,3
```

Number of columns, rows, sections .....    4096    4096       1

Map mode ..............................    2   (32-bit real)
 Start cols, rows, sects, grid x,y,z ...    0     0     0    4096   4096      1

Pixel spacing (Angstroms)..............   1.000      1.000      1.000
 Cell angles ...........................    0.000    0.000    0.000

Fast, medium, slow axes ...............    X    X    X

Origin on x,y,z .......................    0.000       0.000       0.000
 Minimum density .......................   2056.0
 Maximum density .......................   4462.0
 Mean density ..........................   3213.5
 tilt angles (original,current) ........   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0

Space group,# extra bytes,idtype,lens .        0        0        0        0

```
 1 Titles :
```

EMAN 9/18/2015 15:41

I am looking for a shell script where I could specify a range for the "Mean density" value and selected files who contain their "Mean density" value in that range get copied to a new directory.